# Delete from sql server 2000?

Tags: sql, jsp, odbc, sql-server-2000

I want to delete all rows from table in sql server 2000 but whenever I want to delete manually or with query it shows error. In help tab it shows ODBC error: <0s>. 
My table contains some '0' values but its datatype is String. Is that's the reason for this 
error.

code is:

```
stat2=conn.createStatement();
stat2.executeUpdate("Delete * from pat.dbo.PHPL");
```

`"Key column information is insufficient or incorrect. Too many rows were affected by update"` that's warning and when click help it shows: `ODBC error: <0s>. An ODBC error has been generated. You might have deleted a record that has a foreign key value related to it, or you might have violated a check constraint. For details, refer to your ODBC documentation.`

Comment: Can you post the exact error.

Comment: Can you also provide the code that you use? (The delete command)

Comment: "Key column information is insufficient or incorrect. Too many rows were affected by update" that's warning and when click help it shows: ODBC error: <0s>.
An ODBC error has been generated. You might have deleted a record that has a foreign key value related to it, or you might have violated a check constraint.

For details, refer to your ODBC documentation.

Comment: I got the solution; I have to use Truncate command. Thanks :)

Comment: From your error message I guess you use the ODBC driver of sql-server-2000. It could help to use the JDBC driver (both in connection quality and error messages) instead. Google 'sql server 2000 jdbc driver'

Comment: @samikshadhok Then you should select Pauls answer as correct (click the hook left of his answer)

Comment: Thanks @AngeloNeuschitzer, I always feel bad asking people to.

Comment: @PaulMcCowat You shouldn't. The OP most likely is new to Stack Overflow and so doesn't do this because of not-likeing the answer but more likely of not-knowing that it should be done.

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
Truncate Table PHPL
```

I think you have duplicate identities, check you are not allowing duplicates on this column.

Comment: Just remember, when you truncate a table, you cannot rollback. I would avoid it on production servers unless I'm sure I will never would want the information back

Comment: +1 I didn't know that a `truncate` might work where a `delete *` doesn't. Do you care to expand the scenario you had in mind?

Comment: Good point @andydev.  I only use this for test data.  If you have a (primary key?) column and have duplicate values, delete * won't work.

Comment: @andydev - Truncate can be rolled back.

Comment: You're right Martin, but I wouldn't use it if I plan to rollback, since all the identity will change. Lieven, read this: http://sqlblog.com/blogs/denis_gobo/archive/2007/06/13/1458.aspx

Comment: @andydev - A rolled back `TRUNCATE` won't affect the identities. `CREATE TABLE #T(I INT IDENTITY, J INT); INSERT INTO #T VALUES (1),(2),(3); BEGIN TRAN TRUNCATE TABLE #T ROLLBACK; INSERT INTO #T VALUES (4); SELECT * FROM #T; DROP TABLE #T`